# I need to sum the values of one field, based on multiple criteria of other fields in the same query. eg

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have built a database in Access. I now need to interpret the data into a report using probably multiple queries. The issue is that each column is calculated from the source table with multiple criteria.

eg

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Staff Number | Sale Type | Sale Variant | Price |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1            | Brick     |      1       |  £10  |
1            | Sand      |      2       |  £5   |
2            | Brick     |      1       |  £6   |
```

So I want to create a query which outputs each staff number (and a name from a staff table) splitting each variant and type and summing the prices

so

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Staff Number | Brick 1 | Brick 2 | Sand 1 | Sand 2 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1            |   £10   |   £0    |   £0   |    £5  |
2            |   £6    |   £0    |   £0   |    £0  |
```

I can make individual queries easily to sum each column individually, but cant get them into one table or report.

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgerpTHzQes

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select staffnumber,
       max(iif(sale_type = "Brick" and sale_variant = 1, price, 0)) as brick_1,
       max(iif(sale_type = "Brick" and sale_variant = 2, price, 0)) as brick_2,
       max(iif(sale_type = "Sand" and sale_variant = 1, price, 0)) as sand_1,
       max(iif(sale_type = "Sand" and sale_variant = 2, price, 0)) as sand_2
from t
group by staffnumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid continual query maintenance as you add more products & variants, you could use a cross-tab query with the following SQL:

```
transform nz(sum(price),0)
select [staff number]
from yourtable
group by [staff number]
pivot [sale type] & " " & [sale variant]
```